# Styling 2 divs with css on focus or hover of an input

Tags: css, focus, hover

I have a html sturcture like that:

```
<form class="form">
                <div class="row">
                    <input id="search" class="search-input" type="text" placeholder="Search">
                    <div class="input-icon" data-icon="s"></div>
                    <div class="triangle-left"></div>                    
                 </div>
            </form>
```

and the following css code witch is important to know:

```
input[type="text"]:focus, input[type="text"]:hover, input[type="password"]:focus, input[type="password"]:hover {
    border:1px solid #ffa800;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffa800, 0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffa800, 0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px #ffa800, 0 4px 4px rgba(0,0,0,.1) inset;
}
input[type="text"]:focus + .input-icon:before, input[type="text"]:hover + .input-icon:before, input[type="password"]:focus + .input-icon:before, input[type="password"]:hover + .input-icon:before{
    color:#ffa800;
    border-color: #ffa800;
}
input[type="text"]:focus  .triangle-left, input[type="text"]:hover .triangle-left, input[type="password"]:focus .triangle-left, input[type="password"]:hover .triangle-left{
    border-color:transparent transparent transparent #ffa800;
}
```

The first code works great if i hover or focus the input the div with class input-icon get a new color and border-color. My question is can i also make changes in the second div (.triangle-left) ? i have tried it but i doesn't work. only first div is effected. if i change the div so first triangle-left than the css code works.

Do you know a way to do this or is the only possibility to use a small jquery script?

Thanks for your help:)

Regards
Crazymodder

Answer (score 0):

As a quick edit:
http://jsfiddle.net/xngbv/
The problem is that you didn't actually have anything setting `.triangle-left` to use the styles you wanted for hover and focus. `.triangle-left` is a div, not any kind of an input, so the styles you had set in your last block, where you used `.triangle-left`, had no effect

Edit: the changes I made that affected the rendering are using

`.triangle-left:focus, .triangle-left:hover`

instead of

`input[type="text"]:focus  .triangle-left, input[type="text"]:hover .triangle-left`

because the way you had it, the style applies to an input with type text when focused/hovered, that also has style `triangle-left`. Since the only element with class `triange-left` was a `div`, no elements were affected. What you want is to apply the style directly to the element that actually does have `triangle-left` set. If you didn't want to go by just the classname, you could use `div.triangle-left:focus` or something similar.

Comment: hi thanks for your help. But I think there is a missunderstanding. I want to make a hover or a focus on the input and than the div triangler-left and input-icon:before should make some style changes. can you imagen what i mean. i can make a screenshot for you and show it:)

Comment: @user1083404: I don't know what you mean by "than the div triangler-left and input-icon:before should make some style changes". Do you mean that the `.triangler-left` div should change style when the text input is focused? That is usually possible without a script. A screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: Hi yes thats what i mean. I hope the screen helps to show it more clearly what i have planed: http://s14.directupload.net/images/120808/s7v364tn.png Thank you for your help:)